Did Wong Kim Ark limit the holding of Elk v. Wilkins to Indians born on-reservation?
In Elk v. Wilkins (1884), the Supreme Court of the United States ruled that members of Indian tribes, born in the United States, are not "subject to the jurisdiction" of the United States for the purposes of the 14th Amendment. But in United States v. Wong Kim Ark (1898) an important part of the Supreme Court's reasoning for why Wong was subject to the jurisdiction of the United States at birth was:

In short, the judgment in the case of The Exchange declared, as incontrovertible principles, that the jurisdiction of every nation within its own territory is exclusive and absolute, and is susceptible of no limitation not imposed by the nation itself; that all exceptions to its full and absolute territorial jurisdiction must be traced up to its own consent, express or implied; that, upon its consent to cede, or to waive the exercise of, a part of its territorial jurisdiction rest the exemptions from that jurisdiction of foreign sovereigns or their armies entering its territory with its permission, and of their foreign ministers and public ships of war, and that the implied license under which private individuals of another nation enter the territory and mingle indiscriminately with its inhabitants for purposes of business or pleasure can never be construed to grant to them an exemption from the jurisdiction of the country in which they are found. See also Carlisle v. United States (1872), 16 Wall. 147, 155; Radich v. Hutchins (1877), 95 U.S. 210; Wildenhus' Case (1887), 120 U.S. 1; Chae Chan Ping v. United States (1889), 130 U.S. 581, 603, 604.

Did this narrow the holding of Elk to only Indians born on-reservation? It would seem that an Indian born off-reservation would have been in a similar position to a child of foreign nationals. A child born in the United States to Chinese parents is subject to the jurisdiction of the United States at birth, because regardless of what the Chinese government might want them to do, no foreign country can exercise jurisdiction over a person while they're in the United States, leaving only the question of whether the United States itself withholds jurisdiction, i.e., like with children of diplomats. Similarly, an Indian (Native American) born in the United States off-reservation could not possibly be subject to the jurisdiction of their tribe while outside the tribal reservation; they may have been exempt from US jurisdiction in some very limited ways, such as not having to pay certain taxes, but for the vast majority of crimes they could conceivably commit, they would have been fully subject to federal and/or state jurisdiction, not sent back to their reservation to be tried in a tribal court.

I believe this would depend on the legal status of the child at birth.  As I understand it, the lack of US jurisdiction over their persons (and the tribal jurisdiction that existed instead) was not territorial but based on the treaty status that excused them from, for example, taxation by the US.  I don't know much about the details, though, and don't have time to research it, so I can't post a proper answer at the moment.

@phoog I think that might have been true when it came to taxation, but I very much doubt that Indians were exempt from most federal and state criminal laws when not on reservations. And I don't think that just because a person is exempt from taxes, they're exempt from the Citizenship Clause: the framers wouldn't have left such a gaping hole in it that could be weaponized against unpopular groups.

@phoog But perhaps a defensible interpretation is that if someone is a citizen of another nation besides the US (where the Indian tribes are considered to be nations), and the US has a treaty with that nation that grants the tax exemption, then its citizens are not considered "subject to the jurisdiction" of the US for the purposes of the Citizenship Clause.
